# What is the replacement for HttpContext.Current.Session[key] in .net core 2.2 or some code example

Tags: .net-core

what is the replacement of HttpContext.Current.Session[key] in .net core 2.2.Please kindly provide some sample example code

Comment: add some more details to your question to give context to others.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state) :

```
// Requires: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Doctor");
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionKeyAge, 773);

var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
var age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyAge);
```

Hope it helps.